# Open Id Connect SSO on cross platform sites

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I have 3 sites(all were sub domain sites)

1. Server(id.test.com) - .NET
2. Client1(client1.test.com) - Drupal
3. Client2(client2.test.com) - .NET

Am using OpenId Connect for login. My login & logout using drupal site is successful. But when i login through Client2 and navigates to Client1 site automatic login was not made, when i initiates a click in "Login using Generic" button, login occurs.

Is that possible to login automatically? I have checked [OpenId Connect SSO](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect_sso) module which supports only for Drupal sites. Is there is any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenID Connect module is designed only to login your users when they use the login button(s).

The SSO module will propagate the logins to your Drupal sites, if you are using Drupal as authentication provider/clients.

If you are using a cross-platform setup, you will have to create your own auto-login propagation in a custom module. Depending on your authentication provider, you may (or not) be able to define post-login actions to use. Or you may yourself utilize post-login hooks of your Drupal site to trigger logins on the remaining sites.

Unfortunately, the solution you are asking for not only depends heavily on your authentication provider, but also is far out of the scope of Drupal Answers.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my query with an link. Could you check that too?

Comment: Your second question is very likely to be closed for being too broad. Drupal allows many different ways for solving certain problems. Drupal Answers is intended to helping you out with distinct hints/answers when you have questions/issues AFTER you did the research yourself and decided for a way to go but got stuck while doing so. You will most probably not receive fully-grown solutions or startup guidance.

Comment: After research only i have splitted my query in two. I have checked in all drupal sites i found none. also it an customization to be made in it. So i thought of asking for an idea. If you are unsatisfied with my reply, can i modify my query on my facts?

Comment: It's not my satisfaction that matters here. ;) - It's the rules of this QA group. We don't provide ideas, we provide answers to narrowly scoped to-the-point Drupal related questions that are useful to you and others. We won't teach how to use Drupal, nor tell approaches to solve complex problems/realize complex use-cases. That kind of creative work is what you as developer have to do on your own before you ask questions here.

Comment: Okay. my apologies you can go ahead of closing my second question :)